# iron-router does not wait for subscription

Tags: meteor

My router function is defined like this

```
  this.route('time', {
     template: "app",
     yieldTemplates: { 'appNav': {to: 'top'}, 'time': {to: 'appPage'} },
     data: function() {
        console.log("data is ready for time " + (personsSub.ready() && tenantsSub.ready() && teamsSub.ready()));
        return {
           dataReady: personsSub.ready() && tenantsSub.ready() && teamsSub.ready()
        }
     },
     waitOn: function(){
        return [personsSub, tenantsSub, teamsSub];
     }
  });
```

the 3 subscriptions are:

```
var personsSub = Meteor.subscribe("allPersons");
var tenantsSub = Meteor.subscribe("allTenants");
var teamsSub = Meteor.subscribe("allTeams");
```

In the console I can see 2 entries when I navigate to this route

```
data is ready for time false
data is ready for time true
```

I obviously did not understand the meaning of waitOn. The expected result is that the data part be only called once and that it be called after all the subscriptions are ´ready´

Comment: What version of iron router? [Your code should work as-is in 0.9](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/0.9/DOCS.md#waiting-on-subscriptions-waiton).

Comment: it works, it's just that the data function is called 3 times

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
waitOn: [personsSub, tenantsSub, teamsSub];
```

Im not sure the function/return is needed.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but this does not change anything to the behaviour. I am looking for a way to avoid multiple calls

Comment: Akshat's solution worked for me, and the function(){} wasnt working, it seems this is the proper syntax